# How can I rewrite this sentence in the passive?

Tags: passive-voice

I have this sentence:
***"Are they setting up lights outside the stadium?"***

How can I rewrite it in the passive?

Comment: I found the answer, it is:
"Are lights being set up outside the stadium?"

Comment: If you want to be more exact, it’s “Are lights being set up by them outside the stadium?”. But the original is a better sentence; the passive is rather clunky here.

Answer (score 1):

Are the lights outside the stadium being set up?

Comment: Actually the answer was:
"Are lights being set up outside the stadium?"
But your answer did help. Thank you